# VS 2010 db build & deployment with teamcity without VS 2010 installed on build server?

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, teamcity

Has anyone managed to use vs2010 db build & deployment with teamcity without VS 2010 installed on build server?

I've registered the missing DLL's but it doesn't work and seems msdn suggest that we need vs installed on the build server.

Comment: I've managed to do a build wihtout the DB projects when VS isn't installed. I spent some time looking at how to do the same with the DB projects but gave up. Time spent wasn't worth it for me at the time...

Answer (score 0):

Install the Microsoft Windows SDK v7.1 and any other requirements (example being ASP MVC 3 framework), etc.  Make sure you have the correct versions of .NET installed as well.  I am able to build and run unit tests, no issue without Visual Studio 2010 on a windows 2008 r2 64-bit server.

Comment: Are you sure about this? I am talking about VS2010 DB project, no c# related stuff here. Also I found in msdn that they advise you to install VS2010 on build server. Also look at this: http://sqlserverselect.blogspot.com/2010/07/visual-studio-2010-database-projects.html